# Is “I'm working totes” new slang?

Tags: etymology, american-english, slang

I was reading a [*New York Times* article](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/04/18/business/dollar-general-tiktok.html) about a *Dollar General* employee who was fired from her job in Tampa, Florida, when her TikTok videos went viral. In these videos, the retail store manager described the working conditions that she and her overworked staff had to put up with on a daily basis. Delivery trucks that would arrive, often unannounced, abandoning their huge supplies in the store's hallway, blocking aisles and shelves.

Company policy forbids employees to unpack the merchandise until Thursdays and Fridays, which means customers do not have enough room to push their carts. The store manager uses the word "totes" twice in the TikTok video.

> And guess what I get to do? **I'm working totes.**
> So that way **my totes** are actually not sitting here on the floor in my hallway because they're supposed to be done in two days.

[image]

I'm pretty sure it's “totes”, [which *Lexico* says is short for “totally”](https://www.lexico.com/definition/totes) as in “Do you like my new sneakers?” “Totes!” and “‘this is pretty embarrassing but I was totes asleep’” *Merriam-Webster* says it is slang for *totally*, *completely*, and *absolutely*, *definitely*.
My search also revealed that it can also be the plural form of tote bag, a type of canvas shopping bag with long handles.

I searched Google using the string [“I'm working totes”](https://www.google.com/search?q=%20%22I%27m%20working%20totes%22&sxsrf=APq-WBsONU9DBQVKKEj-L6ruto5WLyMQeg%3A1650318195800&ei=c9tdYre0MKyGxc8PteSv6Ac&ved=0ahUKEwj3uc6uyp73AhUsQ_EDHTXyC30Q4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=%20%22I%27m%20working%20totes%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBwgjEK4CECdKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQAFgAYJ4EaABwAXgAgAFbiAFbkgEBMZgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz) and I got three results: one from Facebook posted 31 December, 2019, Tega Cay, SC, USA (South Carolina).

> Amanda Elisabeth I’m working totes today and reminded me of old times!! Miss you both!!

and one from a subreddit called r/DollarGeneral, [the following account](https://www.reddit.com/r/DollarGeneral/comments/ignat7/6am9pm_because_people_wanna_quit_an_hour_before/), which was posted two years ago, provides no location.

> This was a couple of days ago. And it has caused me to have a bit of a mental breakdown. I find myself still needing to rant, so here's how my Saturday went.   […]
> 11-1 [p.m.] : It's so busy. Neither one of us can work **the overstock totes** I pulled out.
> But maybe I can when the new manger i have to train comes in.
> 3:15~ [p.m.]: Phone call at register. **I'm working totes**. Cashier has it.
> The other one is on break. A long line happens, sure I'll help by
> taking cards only. Cashier randomly says they gotta call the boss. I
> ask why. "Oh 'night manager' called. They're quitting."

I know that *totes* is American English, slang, possibly from Southern United States, but what exactly does it mean? Refilling shelves? Stacking? Unpacking boxes?

Moreover, I can't grasp the origins. How is *totes* derived?

Comment: "Totes" is a (brand?) name I've seen associated with large, plastic storage containers. Maybe it's related.

Comment: @LaconicDroid Interesting. Could be, I wonder which came first?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Usually the brand name comes first, and in time becomes a generic and/or metonym. E.g. Google, Kleenex, Aspirin.

Comment: I was very surprised to learn (from the other answers) that "totes" are specific retail packaging units/containers! What I had expected, from the title of the question, was that "totes" would have the sense of "totally", in a contemporary cute contraction sense! The by-now-apparently-archaic sense of "to tote", as "to carry something some distance" was the longer-term sense of the word, as I heard it used frequently by my elderly relatives in southern Indiana c. 1960. I had no idea that that had evolved into an apt name for retail packaging that needed to be moved around. :)

Comment: Understand that "I'm working XXXX" is standard office/store jargon for being in the process of taking individual XXXX objects and processing them somehow.  So "working totes" means taking individual "totes" and, say, removing the items from them and placing the items on the store shelves.  It just means processing in a methodical fashion.

This wording would be understood by most store employees, assuming that "tote" has a meaning in the current context.  (Most people, absent some clues, would assume that "tote" refers to a plastic box/shipping container.)

Comment: @paulgarrett I'm sorry your answer, now converted into a comment,  was so heavily downvoted. I liked your answer because it generally reflected my initial impression of the phrase too! It may not have answered the question but it confirmed that the phrase is not at all common knowledge even among American English speakers.

Comment: Word order makes a big difference.  *"I'm totes working"* would imply the "totally" interpretation of "totes".  But *"I'm working totes"* is the older definition of containers.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, thanks! :)  Luckily my I'm not greatly wounded... :)

Comment: While it’s not relevant to this usage, “totes” for “totally” fits a common pattern for slang terms like “maybs” for “maybe” and “probs” for “probably.” I guess we could say the pattern is to take a stressed first syllable and put S on the end.

Comment: "Totes" *is* indeed widely used slang for "totally". But it's not used that way in this context.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It’s from a standard English word, tote: carry around, or a bag (tote bag) in which to carry things.

In its use in a retail store, it seems that “doing totes” is restocking shelves with merchandise that was taken off shelves but not sold and has been placed in a tote, a container in which unsold items are collected.

In warehouse management a tote may be a sturdy plastic container with a lid; they may run on a track, and the containers may be put on trucks for delivery from a warehouse to a retail establishment.  A warehouse “picker” may have a list to fill with items that go to a particular retail store.

I found but can’t manage to copy many reddit posts about the trials and tribulations of working in warehouses—complaints about people who overfill totes, why some totes have only one item, and so forth.

“Doing totes” is, I think, a down-time task for someone who bags groceries for a cashier.

From https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tote

> ### tote verb (1)
>
> toted; toting
>
> Definition of tote (Entry 1 of 4)
> *transitive verb*
>
> **1** : to carry by hand : bear on the person : LUG, PACK
> **2** : HAUL, CONVEY
>
> ### tote noun (1)
>
> Definition of tote (Entry 2 of 4)
>
> **1** : TOTE BAG
>
> **2** : BURDEN, LOAD
>
> ### tote verb (2)
>
> toted; toting
>
> **Definition of tote** (Entry 3 of 4)
> *transitive verb*
> : ADD, TOTAL —usually used with up
>
> *toted up his accomplishments*
> — G. P. Morrill
> [Entry 4 of 4 omitted]
>
> **First Known Use of *tote***
>
> **Verb (1)**
> 1677, in the meaning defined at sense 1
>
> **Noun (1)**
> circa 1772, in the meaning defined at sense 2
>
> **Verb (2)**
> 1888, in the meaning defined above

Comment: Thank you so much, it now makes more sense to me. So it basically means loading and unloading boxes.  "Working totes" just sounded weird in the TikTok video. Googling the phrase and finding only 3 results also threw me off track.

Comment: @Mari-LouA not just any boxes, but boxes that are literally referred to as "totes". You would be unlikely to see this usage outside a commercial warehouse or stockroom setting.

Comment: @SethR Never heard of the brand in Italy,  but I'm not involved in the world of warehouses or logistics, and I don't know if the company was ever present in the UK market from the 1980s. I wonder if the Brits or the Aussies use this term.

Comment: @Mari-LouA it's not a brand, it's just a word for that type of box. But you would be unlikely to see it used outside a warehouse, and someone who has never worked in a warehouse may not know what you mean if you used it.

Comment: Can confirm, I just visited the warehouse for the company I worked at for the first time and they were talking about "totes" and showed us some plastic bins. I had never heard them referred to as "totes" before, but that's what they're called there.

Comment: So, *technically* "working totes" is [jargon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jargon), not slang.

Comment: @SethR One can go to just about any retail website that sells storage containers and search for 'tote' and get plenty of results...Lowes, Target, Walmart, etc.  Many of these products are labeled as 'tote' on the product itself.  I would not say this was a warehouse or stockroom only term.

Comment: @rtaft the context of "tote" meaning "carry around" or "bag to carry stuff around in" is not a warehouse term. But "tote" meaning "a box of stuff to be moved" is less common in the general public, and is largely a warehousing/stockroom term.

Comment: @Stobor I'm in central Ontario with parents from the midwest USA and northern Ontario, and in my personal experience, a "tote box" is a common, standard term for a plastic box about 70 litres in size ([image](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/4129dZrqXqL._AC_SY780_.jpg)), or 30 to 100 L more generally. The meaning of tote as in "to tote something around" is related but a tote box is its own distinct thing.

Comment: Thanks @user5670895 - that's good to know! I guess it's a regional usage then, because I'm familiar with those boxes, but not that name for them (in Australia). Over here they're usually just called "storage boxes".

Comment: @Stobor “Storage tote” is a common term for the big plastic box with a lid.

Comment: Any job, retail especially, will generate its own jargon, free of any regional or other restrictions.  At my job, taking boxes that were delivered and putting them where they go is called "working delivery."  Working at the box office is often called "working box," even though you'll never find "box" as an abbreviation for "box office" in any dictionary.

Comment: @Exal This suggests another answer to the question, which is that "working totes" is an example of "working" with an object--working the front desk, working the box office, working delivery, working the night shift--phrases that when shortened are the jargon of a workplace.  Other verbs take such objects, like "swimming laps" or "flying New Orleans turnarounds."

Answer (score 34):

In retail, a tote is a common noun used for the reusable plastic boxes with folding lids in which certain shipments are received. "Working totes" then can be taken to mean "unloading totes".

https://www.google.com/search?q=tote+box

The TikTok screenshot shows cardboard boxes, not totes, which is a source of confusion, even though the task is essentially the same.  This photo is more illustrative:

https://www.reddit.com/r/DollarGeneral/comments/py873i/good_thing_i_like_working_totes/

Comment: In the actual video linked from the NYT article, the "I'm working totes" quote comes right after she shows a hard-plastic case that looks like what you're describing. (Sitting open and empty in a shopping cart). 40 sec into the 2 min video: https://www.tiktok.com/@alwaysmrsgundel/video/7080579628636671275?referer_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nytimes.com%2F&referer_video_id=7080579628636671275&refer=embed  That might have been a random clip somewhat separate from the cardboard boxes packing her aisles.

Answer (score 8):

In a retail setting, I would typically classify totes as reusable, durable sealed containers of products that must be sent back empty when the next delivery truck comes to deliver more of them. If you were "working totes," you would be unpacking the items in the containers and putting them on the shelf for sale.

Answer (score 2):

It is not *new* slang, it is industry/job specific slang. If you haven’t worked totes, you are unlikely to recognize the term, but it has been around for a while.

Comment: I don’t think slang is the right word.

Comment: You could call it jargon. I believe, however, that "tote" is too widely used in this sense to consider it jargon. On the other hand, I frequently overestimate what most people know.